# Passing multiple arguments through: `run bash -c ...`

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, assert, bats-core

While trying to `assert_failure` on a function called `some_function`, I'm experiencing some difficulties passing more than 1 argument.

```
load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'
# https://github.com/bats-core/bats-file#Index-of-all-functions
load 'libs/bats-file/load'
# https://github.com/bats-core/bats-assert#usage
load 'assert_utils'

@test "Perform some test." {
  variable_one="one"
  variable_two="two"
  variable_three="three"
  variable_four="four"
  run bash -c 'source src/some_script.sh && some_function 
  "$variable_one" "$variable_two" "$variable_three"'
  assert_failure
  assert_output "$expected_error_message"
}
```

Where the function consists of:

```
some_function() {
    local variable_one="$1"
    local variable_two="$2"
    local variable_three="$3"
    local variable_four="$4"
    echo "variable_one=$variable_one"
    echo "variable_two=$variable_two"
    echo "variable_three=$variable_three"
    echo "variable_four=$variable_four"
}
```

The output shows only the first variable is passed successfully, whereas, the second to fourth are not:

```
 ✗ Verify an error is thrown, if something.
   (from function `assert_failure' in file test/libs/bats-assert/src/assert.bash, line 140,
    in test file test/test_something.bats, line 89)
     `assert_failure' failed
   
   -- command succeeded, but it was expected to fail --
   output (3 lines):
     variable_one=one
     variable_two=
     variable_three=
     variable_four=
   --
```

How can I pass multiple/four variables to the function whilst still running `assert_failure` on it?

### Edit in response to comment

Though I am grateful for the practical solution provided in the comments by KamilCuk, it seems to allow for increases in specificity. For example, `variable_one` might be a variable that is used in multiple functions with different values for different calls to those functions. So ideally, I would not overwrite the "exported" value every time a different function is called. Instead, I think it would be better to pass specific arguments to a specific function.

Comment: `export variable_one variable_two ...`. `While trying to assert_failure on a function ` What does assert_failure do and how does it work? It's not a standard bash command.

Comment: I think this is [Bats](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, the test indeed is a Bats test.

Comment: `export` the variables you want your child process to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the argument normally but skip first one that is reserved in this context:

```sh
bash -c 'source src/some_script.sh && some_function "$@"' _ 'argument a' 'argument B' 'This is c' 'Andy'
```

The output:

```
variable_one=argument a
variable_two=argument B
variable_three=This is c
variable_four=Andy
```